# easy way to comsume http api from excel

Tags: excel, api, http, odata

**TLDR:** I've got a simple http api based in json. Customers want to consume that api from excel. How can I make customers life as easy as possible?

I've got a simple http api based in json. At the moment the api is consumed by our javascript/web front end site which mainly shows the data in a grid. The user is able to do any kind of filtering, that filtering happens in the backend. The grid is going to evolve in the future so you can do all kind of stuff with it like you would do with excel, so we are considering just making the api consumable from excel.

I have looked to **odata** and excel seems to play quite well with it. You can just point to an enpdoint from excel and magically do a lot of crazy stuff. The problem with odata is that it requires too much work. First, the api is in javascript and I can't seem to find a good javascript library that will do the work for me, so I would have to implement the whole protocol. Second, the only thing I am interested in from odata is the query capabilities, not the data bit - I don't want my endpoints exposing the shape of my data. And finally, odata seems kind of "dead".

I am looking to alternatives to odata.

I found out that with excel you can get data from an http json api endpoint quite easily with a [web query](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba), but I see that a bit limiting. 
First, there are some steps involved in setting up the query - so that won't be as trivial as odata for customers. More importantly, I want my calls to the http endpoint to be parametrised for filtering, with **a lot** of parameters, and I can't find an easy way to do that with web query.

Just to clarify, I want the filtering to happen in the backend, not in excel. The api returning all the data and them doing the filtering in excel won't be feasible due to the huge amount of data.

Any thoughts? Does anybody have experience with this?

I would like to know if..

- Is odata the right approach?
- If odata is not the right approach, what would be the best alternative?

Many thanks